# Is it possible to calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ of the conditions?

Tags: analysis, limits

Is it possible to calculate the limit  $\displaystyle  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ of the conditions?

$ a_n>0$ for $ {n \geq 1}$ and

$ a_{n-1} \leq \left(a_{n+2} - a_n \right)^n \leq a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to even think that there exists an infinite sequence satisfying the given inequalities?

Comment: I don't know. And why has not exist?